# rename multiple files at once and keep their backup

Tags: rename

I need to rename many files at once and at the same time want to keep original files as it is.

For renaming I can use

```
rename "s/Nov2012/Oct2014/g" *.conf
```

But I am losing the files *Nov2012*. How can I keep them also?

Answer (score 0):

Copy them first (to a temporal directory, for example), and then rename:

```
> mkdir tmp
> cp "*Nov2012*.conf" tmp
> cd tmp
> rename "s/Nov2012/Oct2014/g" *.conf
> mv * ..
> cd ..
> rmdir tmp
```

Comment: Thanks. But I did that. But just wanted to know if there is a way to do at once.